# Nested try statements in python?

Tags: python, try-catch

Is there a nicer way of doing the following:

```
try:
    a.method1()
except AttributeError:
    try:
        a.method2()
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            a.method3()
        except AttributeError:
            raise
```

It looks pretty nasty and I'd rather not do:

```
if hasattr(a, 'method1'):
    a.method1()
else if hasattr(a, 'method2'):
    a.method2()
else if hasattr(a, 'method3'):
    a.method3()
else:
    raise AttributeError
```

to maintain maximum efficiency.

Comment: Have you tested your theory that the second option is inefficient? It would surprise me if it wasn't more efficient than the first one.

Comment: Oddthinking is likely correct.  hasattr eliminates the need for an exception to be raised.

Comment: Actually, the implementation of hasattr() essentially just calls getattr() and returns False if an exception is raised; see http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r254/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup

Comment: That doesn't mean the second one wouldn't be faster, though. It depends on whether the first method is likely to exist.

Comment: -1: Premature optimization.  Why worry about performance?  The first is clearly what you mean -- just do that and don't quibble about "efficiency" until you can prove that the exception is your bottleneck.

Comment: Lott is correct. the "contrived-example" tag seems quite appropriate though; good class design should obviate the need for this.

Comment: @Miles - The difference is that it's checking for the error in C rather than going through the stack.  Thus, calling hasattr is much faster than calling getattr and catching an exception.  Try benchmarking it and see what you get.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
def call_attrs(obj, attrs_list, *args):
    for attr in attrs_list:
        if hasattr(obj, attr):
            bound_method = getattr(obj, attr)
            return bound_method(*args)

    raise AttributeError
```

You would call it like this:

```
call_attrs(a, ['method1', 'method2', 'method3'])
```

This will try to call the methods in the order they are in in the list.  If you wanted to pass any arguments, you could just pass them along after the list like so:

```
call_attrs(a, ['method1', 'method2', 'method3'], arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 27):

A slight change to the second looks pretty nice and simple. I really doubt you'll notice any performance difference between the two, and this is a bit nicer than a nested try/excepts

```
def something(a):
    for methodname in ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']:
        try:
            m = getattr(a, methodname)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            return m()
    raise AttributeError
```

The other very readable way is to do..

```
def something(a):
    try:
        return a.method1()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        return a.method2()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        return a.method3()
    except:
        pass

    raise AttributeError
```

While long, it's very obvious what the function is doing.. Performance really shouldn't be an issue (if a few try/except statements slow your script down noticeably, there is probably a bigger issue with the script structure)

Comment: I like the second one since it's very readable and straight-forward. If performance is really an issue, the original poster is probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

```
method = (
        getattr(a, 'method1', None) or
        getattr(a, 'method2', None) or
        getattr(a, 'method3')
        )
method()
```

This will first look for `method1`, then `method2`, then `method3`.  The search will stop as soon as one of them is found.  If none of the methods are found the last `getattr` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 4):

How about encapsulating the calls in a function?

```
def method_1_2_or_3():
    try:
        a.method1()
        return
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        a.method2()
        return
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        a.method3()
    except AttributeError:
        raise
```

Comment: Why the "encapsulating" part? just the `pass` is a nice enough idea, it seems to me.

Answer (score 3):

A compact solution:

```
getattr(a, 'method1',
    getattr(a, 'method2',
        getattr(a, 'method3')))()
```

Comment: Compact, but possibly wrong. If `a` has `method1` but *doesn't* have `method3`, then this will fail. The third argument to `getattr` is evaluated before `getattr` is called, which means this code tries to fetch `method3` before it ever considers `method1` and `method2`. See [Ethan Furman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7971414/33732) for a safer alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new-style object:

```
methods = ('method1','method2','method3')
for method in methods:
    try:
        b = a.__getattribute__(method)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    else:
        b()
        break
else:
    # re-raise the AttributeError if nothing has worked
    raise AttributeError
```

Of course, if you aren't using a new-style object, you may try `__dict__` instead of `__getattribute__`.

EDIT: This code might prove to be a screaming mess.  If `__getattribute__` or `__dict__` is not found, take a wild guess what kind of error is raised.

Comment: Definitely use the getattr() function instead of the __getattribute__ method.

Comment: I can't entirely figure out the relative advantages of getattr vs __getattribute__.  There exist objects for which either will raise AttributeError and the other will work.