# Alternative to Consecutive Try/Except Blocks

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

I am fairly new to Python, so I was wondering whether or not there is a more succinct alternative to running tons of consecutive `try/except` blocks as can be seen below?

```
try:
    project_type = body.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-type")]').text
except Exception:
    project_type = 'Error'
try:
    title = body.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-title")]').text
except Exception:
    title = 'Error'
try:
    description = body.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-description")]').text
except Exception:
    description = 'Error'
try:
    category = body.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-category")]').text
except Exception:
    category = 'Error'
...
```

As was suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701466/nested-try-statements-in-python) or [this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947942/elegant-alternative-to-long-exception-chains) I guess I could create lists of variable names and queries, and then use a `for` loop to construct a dictionary for each container item, but are there really no other alternatives which are perhaps more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract the call to `find_element_by_xpath`; this avoids code duplication, and makes your code more readable:

```
def _find_element_by_xpath(body, xpath)
    try:
        return body.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
    except Exception:   # <-- Be specific about the Exception to catch
        return 'Error'

def get_a_specific_xpath(element):
    return f'./div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-{element}")]'
```

Then your code becomes:

```
project_type = _find_element_by_xpath(body, get_a_specific_xpath('project_type'))
title = _find_element_by_xpath(body, get_a_specific_xpath('title'))
description = _find_element_by_xpath(body, get_a_specific_xpath('description'))
category = _find_element_by_xpath(body, get_a_specific_xpath('category'))
...
```

Comment: tbh, i'm so new to python (and selenium) that i'm not sure which exception i'm looking for lol. and i know if you put the wrong `Exception`, itll break the script if a different exception is thrown. **oh, wait, `value = xpath`, wouldn't `value` have to be a parameter too?

Comment: @Anthony, I've now consecutively rejected three of your edits that broke the code; why don't you instead tell me what you would like, and I'll see how to accommodate it.

Comment: lol which attribute do you imagine `.txt` belongs to?

not all xpath paths are `'./div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-{element}")]'` so it must be able to accept any path...

Comment: I understand - you can abstract the path construction to several different functions that will return the specific paths needed... If you need to, you can further abstract the path construction to accept parameters. The key here, which corresponds to your motivation for asking the question, is to keep the main code concise and clear.

Comment: huh? i'm not looking to abstract the paths, as you put. **also, it's `.text`, not `.txt`,** but since you're denying all of my edits... and this should be handled elsewhere in the code, but doesn't really matter if you leave it in your answer

Comment: I've rejected your edits because they broke the code. Anyways, I've provided you with an alternative to consecutive try/except blocks that repeated code and cluttered your program; this answers your question. If it helped you, you can consider accepting it. If you have further problems, please ask another question, I, or someone else will be happy to help, if we can.

Comment: one last question: `get_a_specific_xpath(element)` extracts a substring from the given string?

Comment: No, it adds `element` to the `path` string

Comment: ok, seriously the last question i have: the `f` signifies a particular encoding similar to how `u'string'` indicates that the string is unicode or?

Comment: f-strings are a way to dynamically format python strings - https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: ohhhh it's a shortened syntax of the `format` method?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your code has a lot of clutter is because you have *duplicate code*. You're expressing the same idea (look up a value, set a default if it fails) four times in a row, which naturally means you'll have to write the same supporting code four times as well.

Loops are a great way to fix duplicate code - so using a list of names to look up and creating a dictionary of values is the perfect solution for you here. This lets you write the logic *once* and then use it many times.

(Also: your code duplication led to a bug! The first two try-except blocks assign the `'Error'` value to `description` instead of the appropriate variable. Duplicate code can bite!)

Comment: I'm wondering if there are alternatives to using some sort of loop to construct objects. **Why do you say the first two `try-except` blocks assign the throw exceptions?!?!**

Comment: I mean that you wind up setting `description`'s value to `'Error'`, even if it was actually the `project_type` variable that you failed to look up a value for.

Comment: ohhh, i see what you were referring to now, the typo. damn copy-and-paste